# Google Maps API で、クリックする度に、既存のpolygonを一旦削除後、再度作成するには？

Tags: javascript, api

**Google Maps API で、クリックする度に、追加した地点を加味したpolygonを表示したいのですが、**
・デフォルトの状態

```
  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var triangleCoords = [
    {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
    {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
    {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
    {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
```

---

**下記のような感じにしたら、前回クリックした時に作成したpolygonの上に新たにpolygonが作成されてしまいます**
・クリックする度に、google.maps.Polygonが作成され(?)、前回作成したポリゴンと重なった部分のポリゴン色が濃くなってしまいます

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var triangleCoords = [
//クリックすることにより、「lat」「lng」を動的追加
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
```

---

**試したこと**
・削除後作成すれば良いかと思い、リファレンスを見て、setMapと同じ所に書いてあったremoveを記述したら

```
bermudaTriangle.remove();
bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
```

エラーになりました

> Uncaught TypeError: bermudaTriangle.remove is not a function(…)

[API公式](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple)

Comment: `bermudaTriangle `はコールバック内で宣言されているように見受けられますが、Polygonを受けているオブジェクト`bermudaTriangle `はどこかグローバルで保持しているのでしょうか？Polygonのオブジェクトではない変数または、未宣言の変数にremoveしているので「そんな関数ないよ」と言われているような気がします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

とりあえず解説付きのコードを貼っておきます。

```js
// polygonの座標
var paths = [];

// 地図を初期化
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -18.818486, lng: 169.158182},
    zoom: 9,
});

// polygonの初期化と地図への配置（最初はpathsが空なので何も表示されない）
var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: paths,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
});
polygon.setMap(map);

// 地図クリック時
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(evt){
    // polygonの座標にクリックした緯度経度を追加
    paths.push({
        lat: evt.latLng.lat(),
        lng: evt.latLng.lng()
    });

    // polygonの座標を更新
    polygon.setPaths(paths);
});
```

Comment: 期待通り動作しました。大変参考になりました